# Side effects when going from cluster to single node and back to cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, server, cluster-computing, desktop

I am currently using a cluster with 3 nodes.

Two of these nodes have hardware problems, so while the defects are being resolved, we plan to change the settings to a single node and operate it.

Of course, if the problem with both nodes is resolved, we plan to operate it again as a 3-node cluster. Is there any problem if we do this?

I wonder if there will be no expected side effects.

I haven't tried it yet and will try it if there are no foreseen problems.

Answer (score 0):

you should/could do the following;

1. take a snapshot of your data so that you have a backup
2. set replicas on all indices to 0
3. use an [allocation exclusion](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.6/modules-cluster.html#cluster-shard-allocation-filtering) for the two "bad" nodes
4. let the cluster move all data to the remaining node
5. replace the bad nodes and let them rejoin
6. allow allocation back onto them

this saves having to change config files and can all be done using api calls. it does assume your remaining node can handle all of the un-replicated shards